# SQL count different cases and return a table

Tags: postgresql, count, case

I'm searching for a way to return multiple cases counts.

I have a huge table with 10 miljon + rows and 10 + columns. Now I want to count the amount in two different cases.

Lets say that I have a column with age and one with heights and I want to fill this table:

```
        10 - 15, 15 - 20, 20 - 25 ..... 65 - 70, 70+ 
  -150cm
150-155cm
155-160cm
160-165cm
165-170cm
....
200+cm
```

Since it is a lot of data I dont want to ask the question more than nessary and I prefer if I can get the result in a table format (and not on one row..)

Any suggestions? (running on a postgres db)

**EDIT:**

Thanks ***kordirko*** I think that did the trick, hence I'm now stuck with an "ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" So I can't try it on the actual data.

In the actual data I got something similar to "age" but the "height" looks like this:

```
case
...
      when (st_intersects(line, (select geom from passage_lines where id = 3)) 
      and (bearing > 20 and bearing <= 190)) 
      and st_intersects(line, (select geom from passage_lines where id = 4)) then 3
... 
end as route 
from tbl1 
where date in (valid_dates)
```

(select geom from passage_lines where id = 3) returns one geometry (one passage_line). *valid_dates* is a with satement that finds valid dates.

I want to look at all *lines* with the same *date* and for the "first" intersection I only want to pick the ones with the *bearing* of 20-190. (One *line* doesn't intersect with more than *passage_line*, hence there are many lines every *date*.)

Is it understandable??

Comment: It's not very clear what you have and what you expect, can you provide your DB schema and an example of the expected result ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WITH xxx as (
  SELECT *,
       CASE 
         WHEN height < 150                   THEN '   -150cm'
         WHEN height >= 150 AND height < 155 THEN '150-155cm'
         WHEN height >= 155 AND height < 160 THEN '155-160cm'
         ......
         ......
         WHEN height >= 195 AND height < 200 THEN '195-200cm'
         ELSE '200+cm'
       END As height_groups
  FROM "huge table with 10 miljon"
)
SELECT height_groups,
   SUM( Case when age < 10               then 1 else 0 end ) as "0 - 10",
   SUM( Case when age >= 10 and age < 15 then 1 else 0 end ) as "10 - 15",
   SUM( Case when age >= 15 and age < 20 then 1 else 0 end ) as "15 - 20",
   SUM( Case when age >= 20 and age < 25 then 1 else 0 end ) as "20 - 25",
   .....
   .....
   SUM( Case when age >= 65 and age < 70 then 1 else 0 end ) as "65 - 70",
   SUM( Case when age >= 70 then 1 else 0 end ) as "70+"
FROM xxx
GROUP BY height_groups
ORDER BY height_groups
```

This query will read the table only once.

Comment: can you change data type of column and make it JSON. It will be easy for you to manage it. PostgeSQL 9.3 has this JSON data type support. Please check at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html might be useful to you.